# merge data by groups and by common ID (IDs duplicated outside groups)

Tags: r, dplyr

*This is **not** a duplicated question to [How to join (merge) data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right). You can perform the left.merge inside the group but not to the whole data set. The ids are unique **inside** group, **not** acroos group. **By not grouping** and using a left.merge, you willl **mess up the data**.*

I have a data with many groups (Panel data/Time seriers). **Within** the group, I want to merge the data by a common ID. And apply the same merge across **all the groups** that I have(same `merge` for all other groups).

```
#sample data
a<-data.frame(c(1:4,1:4),1,c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'))
b<-data.frame(c(2,4,2,4),10,c('a','a','b','b'))

colnames(a)<-c('id','v','group')
colnames(b)<-c('id','v1','group')

> a
  id v group
1  1 1     a
2  2 1     a
3  3 1     a
4  4 1     a
5  1 1     b
6  2 1     b
7  3 1     b
8  4 1     b
> b
  id v1 group
1  2 10     a
2  4 10     a
3  2 10     b
4  4 10     b
```

I tried to use the dplyr `group_by (group)` and then `merge(a,b,by='id',all.x=TRUE)`, but not sure how to apply dplyr to two data sets

desired output (left merge)

```
  id v group.x v1 group.y
  1  1       a NA    <NA>
  2  1       a 10       a
  3  1       a NA    <NA>
  4  1       a 10       a
  1  1       b NA    <NA>
  2  1       b 10       b
  3  1       b NA    <NA>
  4  1       b 10       b
```

Comment: Outside of dplyr you have the option `library(data.table); setDT(b)[a, on="id", mult="first"]`

Comment: `a %>% left_join(b, by=c("id","group"))`. This gives you only one "group" column, but `v1` will be `NA` for cases where there's no matching row in `b`, so creating two separate "group" columns is redundant. Isn't that better, given that `group` (presumably) represents the same underlying division of the data in both data frames?

Comment: I think you'll have to make an example that covers such cases. It's not clear to me, anyways, what extension you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just include `group` in the `by` argument for the join:

```
a %>% left_join(b, by=c("id","group"))
```

> ```
>   id v group v1
> 1  1 1     a NA
> 2  2 1     a 10
> 3  3 1     a NA
> 4  4 1     a 10
> 5  1 1     b NA
> 6  2 1     b 10
> 7  3 1     b NA
> 8  4 1     b 10
> ```

This gives you only one "group" column, but `v1` will be `NA` for cases where there's no matching row in `b`, so creating two separate "group" columns is redundant. Isn't that better, given that group (presumably) represents the same underlying division of the data in both data frames?

Comment: your codes work. It assumes the combination of  'id' by 'group' are unique, right? What if a small portion of 'id' by 'group ' are not unique.

Comment: Do you mean that there can be more than one row with same combination of `id` and `group` (but presumably different values of `v`)? As @Frank said, please provide more detail on what you have in mind; preferably by adding example data/code to your question.